# Xamarin.Forms OpenGLView does not work when used inside a XAML page

Tags: opengl, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I tried to use the simple example provided here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.openglview?view=xamarin-forms
to try to create a XAML View with the OpenGLView Class. But I'm running into issues. This is Xamarin.Forms (l, ran on iOS Simulator and using the Prism framework, macOS Mojave and Visual Studio for Mac 2019 Pro.

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
   xmlns:otk="clr-namespace:OpenTK.Graphics.ES3"    
   x:Class="MyApp.Views.OpenGlPage">

   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
       <OpenGLView x:Name="openGLView" HasRenderLoop="true"/>
       <Button Command="{Binding Display}" Text="Display"/>
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and the code behind

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using OpenTK.Graphics.ES30;

namespace MyApp.Views
{
    public partial class OpenGlPage : ContentPage
    {
        float red, green, blue;

        public OpenGlPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "OpenGL";


            openGLView.HeightRequest = 300;
            openGLView.WidthRequest = 300;

            openGLView.OnDisplay = r => {

               GL.ClearColor(red, green, blue, 1.0f);
               GL.Clear((ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | 
ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit));

               red += 0.01f;
               if (red >= 1.0f)
                  red -= 1.0f;
               green += 0.02f;
               if (green >= 1.0f)
                  green -= 1.0f;
               blue += 0.03f;
               if (blue >= 1.0f)
                  blue -= 1.0f;
           };
       }
   }
}
```

The ViewModel does not have much, and the View is properly registered with Prism so the navigating to this view works fine.

But it looks like there is some issue with the way that OpenGL is used or initialized when dropped in XAML like this. When the execution hits any GL.* call application crashes. This is the error:

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
    Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Adddress Reporting
=================================================================
    instruction pointer is NULL, skip dumping
=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x10184704d - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x10183b7a5 - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x10184db43 - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler
    0x10f329b5d - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x18 - Unknown
    0x135d884bf - Unknown
    0x135d88927 - Unknown
    0x101850fa1 - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x10196ab78 - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x10196e4ce - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke
    0x101a8142a - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : xamarin_invoke_trampoline
    0x101a89365 - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : xamarin_arch_trampoline
    0x101a8a761 - /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/602074EE-E100-4319-B9DE-D9460B6264EB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7937567A-2C4D-43A6-8A81-B27BFEF73EF6/Prism1.iOS.app/Prism1.iOS : xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline
    0x1077a8ffd - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit : -[GLKView _display:]
    0x112231c21 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore : -[CALayer display]
    0x112244003 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore : _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE
    0x1121b33aa - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore : _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE
    0x1121ea584 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore : _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv
    0x117924d8a - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate
    0x117a17f5f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __handleEventQueueInternal
    0x10242ebe1 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    0x10242e463 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    0x102428b1f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopRun
    0x102428302 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x11249f2fe - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x11792aba2 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x134910932 - Unknown
    0x1349106c3 - Unknown

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x00211>
  at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x000b2>
  at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00222>
  at Prism1.iOS.Application:Main <0x00092>
  at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object <0x00168>
=================================================================
```

This happens regardless what GL call I have there in the OnDisplay handler. If I remove the GL calls everything works fine of course, minus the OpenGL content :)

Compilation warnings:
[image: Compilation warnings]

Comment: Do you have a warnnings when `using OpenTK.Graphics.ES30;` in project?

Comment: I added the screenshot of the 3 compilation warnings, they do not seem significant to the problem.

Comment: I can confirm i'm seeing a similar issue on android with a near identical setup